# Kinect Depth calculation

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry guys, i am desperate for answer. That is why i didn't follow the rules of this website. I sincerly apologise. For this code, i have come up with a better one.
float cx = 320.0;
float cy = 240.0;
float minDistance = -10;
float scaleFactor = 0.0021;

```
for (int v=0, n=0 ; v<480 ; v++) 
    {
        for (int u=0 ; u<640 ; u++, n++)
        {
                Vec3f result;
                result.x = float(((u - cx) * t_gamma[depth[n]]+ minDistance)   * scaleFactor * (cx/cy));
                result.y = float(((v - cy) * t_gamma[depth[n]]+ minDistance)   * scaleFactor);
                result.z = float(t_gamma[depth[n]]);
        
    
        }
        
    }   
 

// OS X requires GLUT to run on the main thread
gl_threadfunc(NULL);


return 0;
```

}
is this code better? i have tried to save the depth data but all the data is zero. I don't know where is the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10193/kinect-depth-calculation/) by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-06-07

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-09**:
If your depth data is zero, the code above is probably not the problem. Does OpenKinect provide samples? Then use those, otherwise you can still use the ROS node, remove the ROS stuff and use it for yourself (respecting the license of course).

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-09**:
I would  really appreciate any help provided...

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-09**:
I am an intern in a company and i was asked to do this... Using the OpenKinect.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-08**:
Why do you want to do this yourself? Is it an exercise or are you interested in the results. For the latter I would highly recommend using the openni_camera node as it already gives your 3D data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This message is double posted see original one [HERE](http://answers.ros.org/question/1107/kinect-depth-calculation)

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-08**:
It's not really the original. That link was another question before (and should probably be returned to its original question).